# Run 2 WP instances at once

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run 2 wordpress websites via docker compose on one server, 1st is running fine but the 2nd page just shows "error establishing database connection" not matter what I try

I even asked ChadGPT, couldn't get it to work, maybe I need to change some in wp2? Got No fkin Idea

I got following docker-compose.yml, but no idea why it won't work:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  wp:
    build: ./wp-app
    container_name: wordpress-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wp-app:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${DB_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${DB_USER_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_USER_PASSWORD}"
      VIRTUAL_HOST: digital-dreams.eu
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: digital-dreams.eu
    depends_on:
      - db

  wp2:
    build: ./wp-app2
    container_name: wordpress-app2
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8082
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wp-app2:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db2
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${DB_NAME2}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${DB_USER_NAME2}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_USER_PASSWORD2}"
      VIRTUAL_HOST: test.digital-dreams.eu
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: test.digital-dreams.eu
    depends_on:
      - db2

  wpcli:
    image: wordpress:cli
    container_name: wpcli_app
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.conf.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/conf.ini
      - ./wp-app:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "${DB_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "${DB_USER_NAME}"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "${DB_USER_PASSWORD}"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wp

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 50M
      VIRTUAL_HOST: phpmyadmin.digital-dreams.eu
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: phpmyadmin.digital-dreams.eu
    expose:
      - 8081
    links:
      - db:db

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: wordpressdb
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: [
      '--default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password',
      '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
      '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      '--port=3306'
    ]
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./wp-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USER_NAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_USER_PASSWORD}"

  db2:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: wordpressdb2
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: [
      '--default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password',
      '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
      '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      '--port=3307'
    ]
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./wp-data2:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./db_data2:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME2}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD2}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USER_NAME2}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_USER_PASSWORD2}"
     
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"

  acme-companion:
    container_name: acme-companion
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes_from:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./nginx/acme:/etc/acme.sh
    environment:
      DEFAULT_EMAIL: ****@digital-dreams.eu
```

In advance, Thanks!